# Visual Studio , How to display an array of variables in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Suppose we have  class with RandomClass with an instance variable randomVariable :

```
  public class RandomClass { 
     public int randomVariable ;
     public RandomClass(int _randomVariable){
      randomVariable = _randomVariable;
    }

  }
```

Now we have a list of RandomClass :

```
 void Main(){
  List<RandomClass> randomClassList = new List<RandomClass>();
  int count = 0 ;
   while(count<1000){
    randomClassList.Add(count++);

    }
 }
```

The Issue is , in Debug mode if I want to go through all the randomVariable for each randomClass especially  if the variable is nested deeper inside the other instance variables , I'll have to do alot of clicking for each list component .
Is there a better way of displaying the list components variables like this :

```
randomClassList[0].randomVariable = 0; 
randomClassList[1].randomVariable = 1; 
randomClassList[2].randomVariable = 2; 
randomClassList[3].randomVariable = 3; 
randomClassList[4].randomVariable = 4; 
randomClassList[5].randomVariable = 5; 
randomClassList[6].randomVariable = 6; and so on
```

Comment: You can use the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute to control how the debugger shows a specific type, however that probably won't help you with lists. How do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: this works similar to ToString method , however my goal is similar solution but adding code should be in debugging mode , without any permanent modification to the code .

Comment: You can use appropriate expressions in the watch window

Comment: can you give me an example on how you can do something like this : 
```
foreach(var value in list)
    Display(value.variablex.variabley);
```
Where the display method is created in debug mode

Answer (score 0):

You can only use expressions in the watch window, not statements. However, the following works, given your `List<RandomClass>`:

```cs
// Put this in the watch window:
string.Join(',', randomList.Select(x => x.randomVariable))
```

If you get an error saying that "Select is not a member of `List<RandomClass>`" add `using System.Linq` to your source file, even if it's not used in the actual code.

Comment: this works with the lambda however , when  I use the lambda it says node not supported x =>x.randomVariable , and i'm using Linq

Comment: Works for me. Either you have a spelling error or you're using something other than a list. The expression may fail if it is too complicated (such as when you try this on a Dictionary)